# Update created_at for all tables in a single Query postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way in postgres Sql to update all rows's created_at column in all tables in my schema in a single Query or a procedure?

Comment: There is no single statement that can do that. You'll have to iterate through all tables.

Comment: :( thats sad !!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can you please post a possible solution to this?

Comment: This is not a code writing service, sorry. You can query `information_schema.tables`, construct dynamic SQL statements with `format()` and execute them with PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE`.